# python pandas groupby calculate change

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate the value change by group.

This is the python pandas dataframe df I have:

```
Group |   Date      | Value
  A     01-02-2016     16 
  A     01-03-2016     15 
  A     01-04-2016     14 
  A     01-05-2016     17 
  A     01-06-2016     19 
  A     01-07-2016     20 
  B     01-02-2016     16 
  B     01-03-2016     13 
  B     01-04-2016     13 
  C     01-02-2016     16 
  C     01-03-2016     16
```

I want to calculate that for Group A, the values are going up, for Group B they are going down and for Group C they are not changing.

I am not sure how to approach it, since in Group A the values initially decrease and then increase. So should I look at the average change or most recent change?

Should I use pct_change? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html I was not sure how to specify the timeframe fot that.

```
df.groupby.pct_change
```

It would be great if I could visualize it too. Any advice or hint is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `pct_change` in a `groupby`

```
d1 = df.set_index(['Date', 'Group']).Value
d2 = d1.groupby(level='Group').pct_change()
print(d2)

Date        Group
2016-01-02  A             NaN
2016-01-03  A       -0.062500
2016-01-04  A       -0.066667
2016-01-05  A        0.214286
2016-01-06  A        0.117647
2016-01-07  A        0.052632
2016-01-02  B             NaN
2016-01-03  B       -0.187500
2016-01-04  B        0.000000
2016-01-02  C             NaN
2016-01-03  C        0.000000
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

One of many ways to visualize and compare is to see how they grow.  In this case, I'd

- `fillna(0)`
- `add(1)`
- `cumprod()`

---

```
d2.fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().unstack().plot()
```

[image]

---

***setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """Group   Date       Value
  A     01-02-2016     16 
  A     01-03-2016     15 
  A     01-04-2016     14 
  A     01-05-2016     17 
  A     01-06-2016     19 
  A     01-07-2016     20 
  B     01-02-2016     16 
  B     01-03-2016     13 
  B     01-04-2016     13 
  C     01-02-2016     16 
  C     01-03-2016     16 """

df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=[1])
```

Comment: thank you very much, is there a way to create a new dataframe with one column being the group and the second column being the average change?

Comment: @jeangelj do you mean standard deviation?

Comment: no - I can get SD with .describe(); I am looking for the average change, so something like this df_group = df.groupby('Group')
df_new = df_group['Value'].pct_change().mean()

Comment: Yes, that can be done.  Not exactly as you've written it but it can be done.  `df_group.Value.apply(lambda df: df.pct_change().mean())`  But the results from `pct_mean()` oscillate about zero and might mute your observations regarding how much it changes.  `df_group.Value.apply(lambda df: df.pct_change().abs().mean())` might be better.

Comment: thank you; when I use the second option, I don't get negative values, but only positive and "inf"