# Calculating groupby change with pandas for dataframe with other string type columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I came across this question which is pretty similar to what I'm trying to do:
[python pandas groupby calculate change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453325/python-pandas-groupby-calculate-change)

The only problem is that my dataframe is much more complex, as it has a bunch more value columns that I also want to calculate the differences for, and a few columns of string type which I need to keep, but I obviously can't calculate the numerical difference of those.

```
Group |   Date      | Value | Leader |  Quantity
  A     01-02-2016     16.0      John        1
  A     01-03-2016     15.0      John        1
  B     01-02-2016     16.0     Phillip      1
  B     01-03-2016     13.0     Phillip      1 
  C     01-02-2016     16.0       Bob        1
  C     01-03-2016     16.0       Bob        1
```

Is there a way to alter the code so that I can just make the difference apply to the float type values, rather than having to specify which columns are the float type ones by using loc/iloc? So I'd get something like this:

```
    Date    Group      Change in Value    Leader    Change in Quantity
2016-01-02    A             NaN            John            NaN
2016-01-03    A       -0.062500            John             0
2016-01-02    B             NaN           Phillip          NaN
2016-01-03    B       -0.187500           Phillip           0 
2016-01-02    C             NaN             Bob            NaN
2016-01-03    C        0.000000             Bob             0
```

Additionally, would it be possible to change the pct_change to diff? So ideally I'd get something like this:

```
    Date    Group   Leader    Change in Value    Change in Quantity
2016-01-02    A      John          NaN                    NaN
2016-01-03    A      John         -1.0                    0.0
2016-01-02    B    Phillip         NaN                    NaN
2016-01-03    B    Phillip        -3.0                    0.0
2016-01-02    C      Bob           NaN                    NaN
2016-01-03    C      Bob           0.0                    0.0
```

Extra details about my actual dataset:

- For each group, there are two rows (there are only two dates being considered)
- Ideally I want to then be able to slice through the rows so I delete all the ones with the NaN values
- I need all the numerical values to display as floats for consistency

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select_dtypes` and `join`

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes('number')
df_final = df.drop(df1.columns, 1).join(df1.groupby(df['Group'])
                                           .pct_change().add_prefix('Change_in_'))

Out[10]:
  Group        Date   Leader  Change_in_Value  Change_in_Quantity
0     A  01-02-2016     John              NaN                 NaN
1     A  01-03-2016     John          -0.0625                 0.0
2     B  01-02-2016  Phillip              NaN                 NaN
3     B  01-03-2016  Phillip          -0.1875                 0.0
4     C  01-02-2016      Bob              NaN                 NaN
5     C  01-03-2016      Bob           0.0000                 0.0
```

Using `diff`. Just replace `pct_change` by `diff`

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes('number')
df_final =  df.drop(df1.columns, 1).join(df1.groupby(df['Group'])
                                            .diff().add_prefix('Change_in_'))
    
Out[15]:
  Group        Date   Leader  Change_in_Value  Change_in_Quantity
0     A  01-02-2016     John             NaN                NaN
1     A  01-03-2016     John            -1.0                0.0
2     B  01-02-2016  Phillip             NaN                NaN
3     B  01-03-2016  Phillip            -3.0                0.0
4     C  01-02-2016      Bob             NaN                NaN
5     C  01-03-2016      Bob             0.0                0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response (once again)! Just did this but since my dataset is quite large I'm getting much more NaN than I expected but I think it's because I'm doing perc_change() and it's not liking the dividing by 0 - I was wondering how I could use diff() to see if it works with the absolute value instead?

Comment: @MathsicalStudies: if using `diff`, what is your expected output? Could you add the expected output using `diff` to the question?

Comment: @MathsicalStudies: I edited answer to add `diff`. Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Unfortunately I'm still getting more NaNs than expected, but it's probably more to do with my dataset since your answer seems right to me, so I'll accept your answer and try to think of another way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
cols = []
for col in df3.columns:
    if str(col).startswith('Value'):
        cols.append(col)

for i in range(len(cols)-1):
    df["Change " + i] = (df["Value " + i] - df["Value " + i].shift(-1)) / df["Value " + i]
```